# how to perform a break in nested lists?

Tags: python, break

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7,8]]

for i in lst:
    print(i)
    if i == 3:
        break
```

My question is if i == 3, why is there no effect of break in this code, because I'm getting the output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Shouldn't it just print till 3?

Comment: ```lst``` is a list of lists. So ```i``` is a list. A list is never equal to an integer

Comment: Not the same: `print([x for i in lst for x in i if x <= 3])` result: `[1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by users' comments, you're treating a "list of lists" as a list.
Furthermore, you should care about `if` position inside your code.
Try this:

```
nested_lists = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7,8]]

for list in nested_lists:
    for item in list:
      if item <= 3:
        print(item)
      else:
        break
```

As you can see, `if` statement stands above your `print` function.
`Else` condition is also added, to manage the exception.

Comment: Like I said in the comments: ```lst``` is a list of lists. So ```i``` is a list. A list is never equal to an integer

Comment: Yeah, i didnt see nested lists. But the if logic was wrong in any case. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the `while` loop.

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7,8]]

for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        while j <= 3:
            print(j)
            break
```

Comment: thank you...i understood that i is nothing but a list extracted from a lst

Comment: Yes, that is why your codes are returning lists instead of the elements.